# For loop outputting one character per line

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm writing a quick python script wrapper to query our crashplan server so I can gather data from multiple sites then convert that to json for a migration and I've got most of it done. It's probably a bit ugly, but I'm one step away from getting the data I need to pass on to the json module so I can format the data I need for reports.

The script should query ldap, get a list of names from a list of sites, then create a command (which works).

But when printing the list in a for loop it prints out each character, instead of each name. If I just print the list it prints out each name on a single line. This obviously munges up the REST call as the username isn't right.

```
'''
Crashplan query script

Queries the crashplan server using subprocess calls and formats the output

'''

import subprocess
import json

password = raw_input("What password do you want to use: ")

sitelist = ['US - DC - Washington', 'US - FL - Miami', 'US - GA - Atlanta', 'CA - Toronto']
cmdsites = ""


for each in sitelist:
    cmdsites = cmdsites + '(OfficeLocation={})'.format(each)

ldap_cmd = "ldapsearch -xLLL -S OfficeLocation -h ldap.local.x.com -b cn=users,dc=x,dc=com '(&(!(gidNumber=1088))(|%s))' | grep -w 'uid:' | awk {'print $2'}" % cmdsites

users = subprocess.check_output([ldap_cmd], shell=True)

##### EVERYTHING WORKS UP TO THIS POINT #####

for each in users:
    #    subprocess.call(['curl -X GET -k -u "admin:'+password+'" "https://crashplan.x.com:4285/api/User?username='+each+'@x.com&incBackupUsage=true&strKey=lastBackup"'], shell=True)   ### THIS COMMAND WORKS IT JUST GETS PASSED THE WRONG USERNAME
    print each           #### THIS PRINTS OUT ONE LETTER PER LINE ####

print type(users)   #### THIS PRINTS OUT ONE NAME PER LINE ####
```

Comment: See, `users` is a string, so if you loop on it, you're bound to get one letter every time. Rather `split` the string and then run the loop

Comment: Oops. Just FYI that last line was a test of mine. It was supposed to be print (users) . I was trying to see what type was being passed.

Comment: I'm not talking about the line, but the loop. The `each` variable will only receive a letter and some whitespaces because you're looping on a string. Try the answer provided by @alecxe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an output as a string which, when iterated, produce *one character per iteration*.

You should [split it by line breaks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for each in users.splitlines():  
    print each
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Now I've just got to figure out the json printing! Cheers! I'll makes your's the answer when I can (it's making me wait 8 minutes to do it)