# Python 3.6 for loop is only printing one string per line, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am making a small Morse Code translator, and everything works fine; nonetheless, the output is not shown properly.

```
CIPHER = {'E': "⦾", "A": '⦿', 'R': '⦾⦿', 'I': '⦿⦾', 'O': '⦿⦿',
        'T': '⦾⦾⦿', 'N': '⦾⦿⦾', 'S': '⦾⦿⦿', 'L': '⦿⦾⦾',
        'C': '⦿⦾⦿', 'U': '⦿⦿⦾', 'D': '⦿⦿⦿',
        'P': '⦾⦾⦾⦿', 'M': '⦾⦾⦿⦾', 'H': '⦾⦾⦿⦿',
        'G': '⦾⦿⦾⦾', 'B': '⦾⦿⦾⦿', 'F': '⦾⦿⦿⦾',
        'Y': '⦾⦿⦿⦿', 'W': '⦿⦾⦾⦾', 'K': '⦿⦾⦾⦿',
        'V': '⦿⦾⦿⦾', 'X': '⦿⦾⦿⦿', 'Z': '⦿⦿⦾⦾',
        'J': '⦿⦿⦾⦿', 'Q': '⦿⦿⦿⦾',
        '1': '⦾⦾⦾⦾⦿', '2': '⦾⦾⦾⦿⦿', '3': '⦾⦾⦿⦿⦿',
        '4': '⦾⦿⦿⦿⦿', '5': '⦿⦿⦿⦿⦿', '6': '⦿⦾⦾⦾⦾',
        '7': '⦿⦿⦾⦾⦾', '8': '⦿⦿⦿⦾⦾', '9': '⦿⦿⦿⦿⦾',
        '0': '⦿⦿⦿⦿⦿'
        }
def main():
    msg = input("Type your message below:\n\n")
    for char in msg:
        if char == ' ':
            print (' '*7,)
        elif char not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890':
            print ('')
        else:
            print (CIPHER[char.upper()])
```

I would expect the output for "Hello, World!" to be something like this:

`⦾⦿⦾⦾⦿⦾⦾⦿⦿       ⦿⦿⦾⦿⦿⦾⦾⦿⦿⦿`

However, the actual output looks much more like this:

```
⦾
⦿⦾⦾
⦿⦾⦾
⦿⦿



⦿⦿
⦾⦿
⦿⦾⦾
⦿⦿⦿
```

I tried removing and placing commas randomly. Then, I tried removing the '\n' statements on the input, but nothing changed with respect to the output. I tried to use the .splitlines as shown here ([For loop outputting one character per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961360/for-loop-outputting-one-character-per-line)), but it stopped printing completely! Then, I googled it and did not found anything close to this problem, so I started to read more material on Python strings. I found a website (https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/) that has a good amount of material about Python strings, but I could not find anything that could solve my problem there.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: By the way, "char not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890':" could be replaced with "not char.isalnum()"

Comment: I don't know much Morse, but I thought S and O were three dots/dashes (or vice versa). Your O is 2 characters and S has different chars.

Comment: @jackweb thanks for the info, I just started using Python yesterday.

Comment: @NickT it is a variation of Morse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be accustomed to Python2 convention of using comma at the end of `print` arguments to prevent automatically adding newline. This is no longer working in Python3. You should use keyword argument `end=''` instead, like this: `print (' '*7, end='')`

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that distinction. I applied it to all the print statements and it worked wonders!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
print(sth, end='')
```

to print without breaking line.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!